# Usage of new indexes is not as expected

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

In my SQL Server database I have a table of Requests with requestID (int) as Identity, PK and Clustered index. There are approximately 30 other columns in the table.

I am using Entity Framework to access the DB.

There is a function called `GetRequestByID(int requestID)` that pulls all the columns from the Requests table and columns from related tables using inner joins.

Recently, to reduce the amount of data pulled where not needed, I created two additional functions, `GetRequestByID_Lite` and `GetRequestByID_EvenLiter` that return lesser number of columns, and replaced all the relevant calls in the code.
For each of those functions I created a corresponding non-clustered index by requestID and including only the columns each function needs.

After one hour, first thing I see is that the memory consumed by the process decreased dramatically.
When I ran `SYS.DM_DB_INDEX_USAGE_STATS`, I see the following for the new indexes:

`_index_for_GetRequestByID_Lite` -      0 seeks, 422 scans, 0 lookups, 49 updates
`_index_for_GetRequestByID_EvenLiter` - 0 seeks, 0 scans,   0 lookups, 51 updates

My question is why so many scans and no seeks for `_index_for_GetRequestByID_Lite`?
If the index doesn't contain all the columns required, then why doesn't SQL Server just use the clustered index?
And why  `_index_for_GetRequestByID_EvenLiter` is not being used at all (there is no doubt the function `GetRequestByID_EvenLiter` is called a lot)?

Also, when I run an SQL query equivalent to `GetRequestByID_EvenLiter`, the Clustered index is used in execution plan instead of `_index_for_GetRequestByID_EvenLiter`.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

SQLServer might not have found your index effective in terms of cost.

see below example

```
create table
test
(
col1 int primary key,
col2 int,
col3 int,
col4 varchar(10),
col5 datetime
)

insert into test
select number,number+1,number+2,number+5,dateadd(day,number,getdate()) 
from numbers
```

Let's create an index

```
create index nc_Col2 on test(col2)
include(Col3,col4)
```

Now if we run a query like below

```
select * from test 
where col2>4
```

and see execution plan cost...

[image]

You might have thought sqlserver should have used above index,but it didn't.Now let's observe the cost when we force sqlserver to use that index

```
select * from test with (index (nc_col2))
where col2>4
```

[image]

In summary ,the reason being your index might not be used may be due to

- It is not cost effective compared to other existing possibilties
- your index is not efficient as shown in my example( i am selecting * and index has only three columns)

also there are some more concepts like allocation scan,sequential scan,but in summary SQL has to believe your index costs less.Check out below links to see how to improve costing

**Further reading:**
[Inside the Optimizer: Plan Costing](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/09/01/inside-the-optimizer-plan-costing.aspx)
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23716/31995

Comment: You use select *, the index doesn't contain all the required columns.
My index does.

Comment: It is an example to show how costing works,your other index might be usefull to sqlserver than the  unused one.

Comment: I forced the second index on the query and turns out it's the same cost as clustered index. That's why it's not used.
Still unclear about the first index why 0 seeks and only scans.